# save txt file in folder windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Having problems trying to save a txt file in a specific folder, the name of the txt file is inserted by the user,the directory is created with no problems, but the txt file isn't saved, I can only get to save the text file when I don't use the  folder (which is not what I want), any ideas on this? any help would be appreciated.

```
 IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                string directory = "data";

    if (!myIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists(directory))
                    {
                    myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory(directory);   //create the folder where the data will be placed
                    }


                   string name = textbox1.Text;

                   using (StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(directory+"\\"+name+".txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, myIsolatedStorage)))
                    {
                        int total_number_of_points=(App.Current as App).number_of_random_points + (App.Current as App).number_of_foresight_points;

                        writeFile.WriteLine("Point  East        North    Height  STD-E STD-N STD-H    Longitude        Latitude     Description");
                        for (int n = 1; n <= total_number_of_points; n++)
                        {

                            string point_data = "";
                            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                            {
                                point_data = point_data + " " + Convert.ToString((App.Current as App).point_information[n, i]);

                            }
                            point_data = point_data + " " + Convert.ToString((App.Current as App).point_description[n]);
                            writeFile.WriteLine("  " + Convert.ToString(n) + " " + point_data);
                        }
                        writeFile.Close();
                     }
```

Comment: I think it could be help to you.. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/74f20d/isolated-storage-to-save-and-read-text-file-from-windows-pho/

Comment: have checked it, doesnt help, but thanks for the response

Comment: @user2404878, any exception? What evidences do you have that the file wasn't saved?

Comment: Paulo Morgado, im using the isolated storage explorer, it doesnt show the txt file when i save it in the folder,

Comment: don't use isolated storage explorer, use Windows phone power tools. ISE has some known bugs with detecting files in subfolsers.

Comment: http://wptools.codeplex.com/

Comment: thank you for the answer Anton, will not use isolated storage explorer again